# Stack overflow and not deadlock

Tags: java, deadlock, stack-overflow

There is stack overflow as the output. Whats the reason behind it?
No matter even if I put sleeps the output remaisn the same as stack overflow error? When can I see deadlock in this program?

```
public class DeadLock extends Thread    {
    private static String o1  = new String();
    private static String o2  = new String();
    private String info;

    public DeadLock (String info) {
        this.info    = info;
    }

    private void inProtected_1 () {
        synchronized ( o2 )   {
            inProtected_2();
        }
    }

    private void inProtected_2 () {
        synchronized ( o1 )   {
            inProtected_1();
        }
    }

    public void run () {
        if ( info.equals("first") ) {
            synchronized ( o1 )   {
                inProtected_1();
            }
        } else
            synchronized ( o2 )   {
                inProtected_2();
            }
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
        new DeadLock("second").start();
        new DeadLock("first").start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Locking on a string is a bad idea.

Comment: @SLaks Its nice to say something is a bad idea ... but to explain why is a little more complicated. So if you say A then continue with B also, else please dont waste the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use sleep to get more guaranteed deadlock. For example it creates deadlock on my machine:

```
public class DeadLock1 extends Thread    {
    private static String o1  = new String();
    private static String o2  = new String();
    private String info;

    public DeadLock1 (String info) {
        this.info    = info;
    }

    private void inProtected_1 () {
        synchronized ( o2 )   {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            inProtected_2();
        }
    }

    private void inProtected_2 () {
        synchronized ( o1 )   {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            inProtected_1();
        }
    }

    public void run () {
        if ( info.equals("first") ) {
            synchronized ( o1 )   {
                inProtected_1();
            }
        } else
            synchronized ( o2 )   {
                inProtected_2();
            }
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
        new DeadLock1("second").start();
        new DeadLock1("first").start();
    }
}
```

Basically I added sleep after each thread locked his string and before it locked string of the other thread. This way I guarantee that when threads try to lock second string - it already locked and we get deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `synchronized` lock are re-entrant.

So your first thread acquires the lock on `o1` and also on `o2` and keeps looping. That is why you get a `StackOverFlow`. The second thread simply waits on the first lock.

To actually get a deadlock, add a `sleep` to your methods so that both threads can acquire one lock:

```
private void inProtected_1 () {
    synchronized (o2) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);    // simulate work
        inProtected_2();
    }
}

private void inProtected_2 () {
    synchronized (o1)   {
        Thread.sleep(1000);   // simulate work
        inProtected_1();
    }
}
```

In addition, to make sure not to synchronize on the actual same object, use `new Object()` instead of `new String()`

Comment: How does it keep looping?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a context switch right after you perform `synchronized(o1)` in your `run()` method.  After a context switch you would have Thread 1 holding `o1` and Thread 2 holding `o2`.  When either one tries to synchronize on the opposite o-value you result in deadlock.  You need another lock around each synchronize operation.

Also, try not to use synchronize, you should use actual `Lock` objects.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with synchronize. Locks have a more comprehensive API, there a more lock implementations to choose from, multiple conditions, timed waits, but if you don't need that, it isn't the end of the world to use the intrinsic lock (so synchronized).

Answer (score 0):

The first of your threads to start will conceivably get both locks. It will then call itself so many times that you will get a stack overflow, while the other thread just sits there waiting for a lock. If you add a print statement to one of the methods printing out the 'info' variable, you will probably see the same info printed out on every line.

Answer (score 0):

Placing lock on String is dangerous.

According to Section 3.10.5 of the Java Language Specification:

Literal strings within different classes in different packages likewise represent references to the same String object.

What this means is that if another class contains the same string literal, it will refer to the same String object and could result in a deadlock.

Comment: There is no locking on literal.

Comment: But these aren't literal strings. His locks are no different than if he'd said `private static Object o1  = new Object();` Also, your warning that it could result in a deadlock is kind of funny since I think the whole point here is that he is **deliberately** trying to cause a deadlock.